# Blend-Files Preview Thumbnails with Background Images

Tags: camera, blend-files, file-browser

in March 2019 when Blender 2.8 non-stable was released, there was a feature added which is apparently missing now from the 2.8 stable release.

In the previous release you could see the camera background images in your .blend thumbnail preview.

With 2.8 stable they're all gone. Is there any way to get this feature back?

[image: Old version thumbnails]
[image: New version thumbnails]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried saving the file in a different viewport shading mode? This might have to do with the file state at saving time

Comment: No sorry, I've tried saving it with each viewport shading and it still doesn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In the Blender File Browser was able to show previews by clicking on box shown and the clicking on show previews.[image]

My bad, did not notice I was in 2.81. Switched to 2.80 and does not work.
Sorry for incorrect information.
In my present version of 2.81 the settings in preferences don't stick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see the thumbnails, but i want to see the camera background image in it – that feature is missing since 2.8 stable.